# Clear plan for self-study?

Tags: self-learning

I'm still student in university, and I need 2 years to graduate, but the thing is I still don't know anything about computer science other than problem solving, C++/Python OOP and DataStructure; I know these are heavy important subjects but I'm still lost, my university is also lost for me and I have the power to learn more and more alone but all I need is a clear plan to do that..

I think this question had been asked hundreds of times.. But still there's no good enough answers.. So let me rephrase the question and ask this :

***How to know what kind of majors do I want to learn and work with in the future as graduated computer science student? AND Where to find a tree-plan of skills that I need to learn to reach my goal on that major? AND When I find that tree of skills, Where to learn those skills other than my University?***

So I need to know what major I do really need, and how to learn it in a very good way..

Please give me any helpful websites, articles, tests to know what major I want (idk if that's even exist) and anything you see it could help me :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Moha, welcome to [cseducators.se]!  I'm having trouble deciphering this text: "what kind of majors do I want to learn and work with in the future as graduated computer science student". Could you clarify?

Comment: Hey ben, We know the expansive of careers in CS e.g. "Android Development", "Data Science", "Artificial Intelligence", "Web developer" and etc...
I don't know what really fit me among those careers, but I really need to know.
What I meant in my question is "How to know what career that fits me among of all these careers?".

Comment: Oh, I see! That question is way out of the scope of this site (or any stack exchange site).  For life advice, is there a faculty advisor you could reach out to?

Comment: I'd add as well that there are effectively infinitely more careers in CS than you are considering; every field and every walk of life is bring touched by CS, so it is basically everywhere.  Forgetting about careers for a moment, what parts of CS seem interestinf to you? That's a good starting point.

Comment: Yes there's a faculty advisor in my university, I will ask him one day.. but actually I don't really trust him that's why I'm here.

I heard that (In general) there's about 21 main career in CS and you are able to merge every 2 of them to get you a new career!  and that's explain how we find CS in every thing in our life. This is actually awesome! but in the same time scary for me imagining myself in a maze named "CS" and there's tens of paths I have to choose one of them while I don't know what is the best for me..

Comment: You asked what is the interesting part of CS for me..

I would say coding in general, 2 years of coding and still love the idea that I am using a programming language to tell the computer what to do, but what I really hate is work in the same pattern every time (routine) that's why I love Problem Solving.
I like challenges and critical thinking, I'm good at that.

These things I said is what made me love CS from the first week of university till now.

Comment: You said "websites articles tests". (Did you mean texts?) Books are important — even if currently unfashionable see https://medium.com/bits-and-behavior/computer-science-taught-me-that-books-werent-important-it-was-wrong-63ead2fdad7a I could list some of the(for me) critical books if you wish

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for career advice.

Comment: @Flater I intended to come back to this question and close it, but it fell off my radar. Thanks for the flag!